# Modelsim shows an unknown warning about vmap command

Tags: modelsim

I created the library "work", but then when I try to use the command "vmap work work" I get the following warning about 20 times in a row: " ** **Warning: (vmap-7) Failed to open lock file "C:/intelFPGA/20.1/modelsim_ase/win32aloem/../modelsim.ini_lock" in create mode.
Permission denied. (errno = EACCES)**".

Afterwards it shows the following error: "**-- Giving up waiting on lock. Lockfile is "C:/intelFPGA/20.1/modelsim_ase/win32aloem/../modelsim.ini_lock".
** Error: WriteIniString C:/intelFPGA/20.1/modelsim_ase/win32aloem/../modelsim.ini failed: 2**".

I couldn't find anything about this create mode or modelsim.ini_lock in my pc, google or this site. However, the vhd files run as expected.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the permission settings of modelsim_ase?
I had the same problem occur after I modified the settings.

My solution is to open the property settings of the file "modelsim.ini" in modelsim_ase folder and make it "read-only".